# Fresh OwnCloud Installation Loads Blank White Page

Tags: openssl, owncloud

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I just installed the latest version of owncloud on my lamp installation located at `/var/www/html/owncloud/`

**Problem:** owncloud serves blank white page at https://someothersite.org/

**useful info:** I already have multiple wordpress installations using the OpenSSL certificate pointing to /var/www/html/ on port 443

**UPDATE**
I tested my SSL by adding phpmyinfo.php to the /var/www/html/owncloud/ directory and successfully reached the url https://someothersite.org/phpmyinfo.php so the SSL warnings are not causing SSL to block files in the directory.  I suspect the problem are not caused by SSL.

In my `owncloud.conf` file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName someothersite.org 
    ServerAlias www.someothersite.org 
    
    # If this is the default configuration file we can use: 'ServerName localhost' or also 'ServerAlias localhost'.

    ServerAdmin info@thesolutiontopoverty.org

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/someothersite.org.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/someothersite.org.access.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud/
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/owncloud>
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    #My Edit
    SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
   
 

</VirtualHost>
```

In my `/etc/hosts` file I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.0.1   someothersite.org
```

In my someothersite.org.error.log I have the following error:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01906: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01909: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01906: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01909: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding your blank Owncloud page:

It seems that your Owncloud produces some errors. Those errors from the Owncloud are handled by Owncloud itself. I had a look into the Owncloud documentation: https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/troubleshooting/providing_logs_and_config_files.html.
The Owncloud logfile is under `data/owncloud.log` in your case it should be here: `/var/www/html/owncloud/data/owncloud.log`

## Regardings your SSL warnings:

It seems that you have created a CA certificate instead of server certificate. This topic has been already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138517/apache-warns-that-my-self-signed-certificate-is-a-ca-certificate

Comment: So your suggestion is remove current certificate and install a new certificate of a different type and that will solve the blank page owncloud homepage problem?

Comment: I do not know your overall server and certificate setup. I would recommend to create a new self signed certificate based on the linked answer and use this in your apache config. Then the warnings in the apache errorlog should not come again.

Comment: I tested my SSL by adding phpmyinfo.php to the /var/www/html/owncloud/ directory and successfully reached the https://someothersite.org/phpmyinfo.php so the SSL warnings are not causing SSL to block files in the directory.  I suspect the problem is something else.